# Table generates twice while only being called once

Tags: reactjs

I have created a simple React project that generates assessment due dates based on the course start date.

The app works OK, except it loops through the code twice.

The first time it takes in the correct date from the Date picker as props and outputs the correct array.

However the second time it takes the LAST date generated, uses that as the props.startDate and runs it again. You only see the second iteration in the browser.

I used 2 table components and the same issue replicated (hence the Table2.js)

Project https://github.com/Netchicken/NZBATTimetableGenerator/tree/master/src/components

Table code from here  https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/basic?file=/src/App.js:1844-1855

```
Homejs called from Home
    <Table2 startDate={startdate2}></Table2>
```

Table2.js

```
function Table2(props) {
const columns = React.useMemo(
() => [
  {
    Header: "NZBAT Assessment TimeTable",
    columns: [ ... deleted for brevity ....
     ]
  },
],
[]
);
const date = props.startDate;
console.log("Table2 props", date);
const data = React.useMemo(() => loadAssessmentsFile(date), [date]);

return (
<Styles>
  Course Start Date: {date.toDateString()}
  <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
</Styles>
);
}

export default Table2;
```

Assessments.js

```
export default function loadAssessmentsFile(dateStart) {
const data = assessemnts;
console.log("AFile dateStart in", dateStart);
const date = dateStart;
const options = {
weekday: "long",
year: "numeric",
month: "long",
day: "numeric",
};

data.map((data, i) => {
//  console.log("in", data.DueDate + " " + data.days);
var newdate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + data.days));
data.DueDate = newdate.toLocaleDateString(undefined, options);
console.log("out", data.DueDate);
});

return data;
}
```

Console Logs

```
//first iteration
Table2 props Tue Apr 14 2020 11:58:27 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)
Assessment.js dateStart in Tue Apr 14 2020 11:58:27 GMT+1200 (New Zealand 
 Standard Time)
out Tuesday, April 14, 2020
(...)
out Tuesday, June 2, 2020

   //second iteration
Table2 props Tue Jun 02 2020 11:58:27 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard 
 Time)
Assessment.js dateStart in Tue Jun 02 2020 11:58:27 GMT+1200 (New Zealand 
 Standard Time)
out Tuesday, June 2, 2020
(...)
out Tuesday, July 21, 2020
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. 
The Table2 is using React.Memo. This watches startDate, if no change just returns the same data without calculating it

The dependencies list are the elements useMemo watches: if there are no changes the function result will stay the same, otherwise it will re-run the function.

Of course the startDate is also including a time element, which is always changing, so its always running again.

Why it used the last date generated I still don't know but turning it to a .toDateString(); fixes it.

```
const data = React.useMemo(() => loadAssessmentsFile(date), [date]);
```

It still runs twice, but since the date isn't changing the output remains the same.

50% success rate :-)